# remove all the element smaller then X in a array which is a value in dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, loops, dictionary

let's assume we have a dictionary 'd' with key '1' and the value of '1' is a list '[11,22,33,44]' then how can we remove all values less than 30?

I tried to run a loop and use the remove function:

```
d={1:[11,22,33,44]}
for j in d[1]:
    if j<=30:
        d[1].remove(j)
print(d)
```

the result I was expecting was: {1: [33, 44]}
but instead after removing the 1st element the loop stopped and gave me: {1: [22, 33, 44]}

Comment: Do you mean "less than or equal to"? Either way , it will be good to sync your text and code.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is a classic problem of removing items from a list

When you remove item #0, everything else shuffles up, so that the old item #1 moves into place #0.

On the next iteration, the loop looks at the *new* #1. Therefore the *original* #1 escapes the testing!

#### You could work backwards through the list

That is the standard solution for most programming languages.

#### The more pythonic solution is to recreate the list without the unwanted elements

Python's list comprehensions are designed to make this very easy:

```
d={1:[11,22,33,44]}

d[1]=[element for element in d[1] if element>30]

print(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify a list when iterating over it. Better to reconstruct the list as follows:

```
d = {
    1: [11,22,33,44]
}
d[1] = [n for n in d[1] if n >= 30]
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
{1: [33, 44]}
```